# Laravel - email uniqueness validation fails

Tags: validation, email, laravel

I have the following rules:

```
$rules = array(
                'name'          => 'required|alpha_num|unique:users,username',
                'password'      => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
                'email'         => 'required|email|unique:users'
            );
```

`unique` checks for existing emails properly, HOWEVER, if I input an invalid email address (something like kolę@ddd.com) I get a "Woops, something went wrong" laravel error. It seems that the validation doesn't stop at the `email` rule and the wrong email address is being passed to the `unique` rule. If I remove the `unique` rule it works properly, but doesn't check if a certain email exists. How do I solve this?

Comment: kolę@ddd.com is a valid email

Comment: But the validator still fails. Why is that?

Comment: So what's is the issue here? the email provided is valid, so validator should pass, unless it's already in the database.

Comment: The validator fails when I provide that email. That's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out what was causing the validator to fail: mysql table row collation.

I've set it to `utf8-general-ci` and it's all working now.